# Prove or disprove. Every graph G is a spanning sub graph of some graph H where H is of regular maximal degree of G.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove or disprove. Every graph G is a spanning  sub graph of some graph H where H is of regular maximal degree of G.

Im thinking this is false. But why?

Comment: What do you mean by "$H$ is of regular maximal degree"?

Comment: Meaning that its regular up to the max degree of its vertices. Ex. If the max degree in H was 3, then all of its vertices would be of degree 3, although it need not to be H=k4

Comment: Then wouldn't it be enough to let $H$ be the complete graph on the vertices of $G$?

Comment: That would show its correct. But when we spoke about this problem in class, the professor mentioned it was a false statement, our job was to come up with an example but I can't see why this would be false.

Comment: Perhaps he meant that the degree of $H$ should be equal to the maximal degree of the verties in $G$?

Comment: Holy crap you're right, it does max degree of G!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a graph G with 5 vertices and degree sequence 3,3,2,2,0.

In order to be a spanning u graph that is 3 regular, H must have 5 vertices with degree 3 on each vertex ( impossible).

Thus, this statement is false.

Does this work?

Comment: Given the clarification that $H$ must be regular, of degree the maximal degree of $G$, it works. Note the slightly simpler example assigning three vertices and degree sequence $1,1,0$, i.e. $G$ is one edge of a triangle.